# JSON parsing object/array

Tags: apex, json, parsing

I am trying to parse JSON but an error comes when the data comes in array format, I tried to typecast the untypedMap in Object and used instanceof to check if it is Map<String, Obejct> or List<Map<String, Object> but it always returns false.
Is there any way to check for object/array in JSON?

Answer (score 1):

You should have an idea of the JSON that you're working with before you get it, and the source of the JSON should (ideally) stick to giving you a single, well defined "schema".

That is, if you're going to get a list, you should always get a list.

If, for some reason, your JSON can switch between starting as a list or starting as an object, then I think your only realistic option here is to check the first character of the JSON string.

`[` => deserialize as a `List<Object>`
`{` => deserialize as a `Map<String, Object>`